# ActiveMQ Artemis fails to authenticate against OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, activemq-artemis

I'm having a simple setup locally running in docker containers, one container based on `openjdk:13-alpine` installing artemis `2.11.0` and the other based on `osixia/openldap`.

When I try to login to the web console I receive an error that I cannot understand at all:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /console/auth/login/. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:
java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Line 11: expected [option value], found [null]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:242)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:240)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:240)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:378)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:451)
    at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.doAuthenticate(Authenticator.java:128)
    at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:92)
    at io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.XXSSProtectionFilter.doFilter(XXSSProtectionFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.CacheHeadersFilter.doFilter(CacheHeadersFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.SessionExpiryFilter.process(SessionExpiryFilter.java:117)
    at io.hawt.web.SessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(SessionExpiryFilter.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.RedirectFilter.process(RedirectFilter.java:73)
    at io.hawt.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Line 11: expected [option value], found [null]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.match(ConfigFile.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:479)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 61 more
Caused by:
java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    Line 11: expected [option value], found [null]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.match(ConfigFile.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:479)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:242)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:240)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:240)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:378)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:451)
    at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.doAuthenticate(Authenticator.java:128)
    at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:92)
    at io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.XXSSProtectionFilter.doFilter(XXSSProtectionFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.CacheHeadersFilter.doFilter(CacheHeadersFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.SessionExpiryFilter.process(SessionExpiryFilter.java:117)
    at io.hawt.web.SessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(SessionExpiryFilter.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at io.hawt.web.RedirectFilter.process(RedirectFilter.java:73)
    at io.hawt.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

The same kind of error occurs when I try to use the `bin/artemis producer` command from within the Artemis container itself:

```
2020-03-26 15:44:34,845 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841000: created connection: RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=e66c8100, clientID=null, nodeID=1fa3713e-6926-11ea-b9f9-0242c0a8d002, transportConnection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyServerConnection@3d04dde0[ID=e66c8100, local= /127.0.0.1:61616, remote=/127.0.0.1:40444]]
2020-03-26 15:44:34,937 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224018: Failed to create session: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
   Line 11: expected [option value], found [null]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137) [java.base:]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102) [java.base:]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [java.base:]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [java.base:]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [java.base:]
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) [java.base:]
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166) [java.base:]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404) [java.base:]
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591) [java.base:]
   at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255) [java.base:]
   at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:246) [java.base:]
   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554) [java.base:]
   at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:245) [java.base:]
   at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:242) [java.base:]
   at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:240) [java.base:]
   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312) [java.base:]
   at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:240) [java.base:]
   at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:501) [java.base:]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.getAuthenticatedSubject(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:190) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.validateUser(ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager.java:99) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:137) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createSession(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1530) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handleCreateSession(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:166) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handlePacket(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:88) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:720) [artemis-core-client-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:408) [artemis-core-client-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:385) [artemis-core-client-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:654) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73) [artemis-core-client-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:796) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:427) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:328) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) [netty-all-4.1.34.Final.jar:4.1.34.Final]
   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
   Line 11: expected [option value], found [null]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:665) [java.base:]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.match(ConfigFile.java:578) [java.base:]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.parseLoginEntry(ConfigFile.java:479) [java.base:]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.readConfig(ConfigFile.java:426) [java.base:]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:329) [java.base:]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:271) [java.base:]
   at java.base/sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135) [java.base:]
   ... 45 more

2020-03-26 15:44:35,033 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841001: destroyed connection: RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=e66c8100, clientID=null, nodeID=1fa3713e-6926-11ea-b9f9-0242c0a8d002, transportConnection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyServerConnection@3d04dde0[ID=e66c8100, local= /127.0.0.1:61616, remote=/127.0.0.1:40444]]
```

The log does not reveal which file is to blame (even in level `DEBUG`) - I assume the `login.config` though, but I cannot see any issue in there.

I really appreciate any hints about either invalid Artemis configs or invalid LDAP records which could cause such issues.

The broker seems to be able to read data from LDAP - at least authorization wise - as the logs show details for the population of roles, such as:

```
2020-03-26 14:45:24,021 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221051: Populating security roles from LDAP at: ldap://ldapserver:389
...
2020-03-26 14:45:24,240 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LegacyLDAPSecuritySettingPlugin] LDAP search result: cn=read,cn=public.foo.test1.\#,ou=Topic
    Destination type: topic
    Destination name: public.foo.test1.#
    Permission type: read
    Attributes: {member=member: cn=admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com, cn=users,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com}
    Role name: admins
    Role name: users
...
```

**Side note**: I'm receiving a log after the above messages that indicates some issues with the pagination support:

```
2020-03-26 14:45:24,231 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224086: Caught unexpected exception: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 12 - critical extension is not recognized]; remaining name 'ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com'
```

However, as it seems this pops up AFTER the first chunk of records have been processed - if I'm not wrong the default items-per-page limit should be 500, fairly enough for my current case.

I've configured the artemis configs as follows:

`login.config`:

```
openldap {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule required
        debug=true
        initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
        connectionURL="ldap://ldapserver:389"
        connectionUsername="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
        connectionPassword="..."
        connectionProtocol="s"
        connectionTimeout=10000
        readTimeout=10000
        topicSearchMatchingFormat="cn={0},ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com"
        topicSearchSubtreeBool=true
        authentication=simple
        ignorePartialResultException=true
        userBase="ou=User,dc=example,dc=com"
        userSearchMatching="(uid={0})"
        userSearchSubtree=false
        queueSearchMatchingFormat="cn={0},ou=Queue,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com"
        queueSearchSubtreeBool=true
        roleBase="ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com"
        roleName="cn"
        roleSearchMatching="(member:=uid={1})"
        roleSearchSubtree=true
    ;
};
```

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<configuration ...>
  <!-- ... SNIP ... -->
    <security-settings>
      <security-setting-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LegacyLDAPSecuritySettingPlugin">
        <setting name="initialContextFactory" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
        <setting name="connectionURL" value="ldap://ldapserver:389"/>
        <setting name="connectionUsername" value="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"/>
        <setting name="connectionPassword" value="...SNIP..."/>
        <setting name="connectionProtocol" value="s"/>
        <setting name="authentication" value="simple"/>
        <setting name="destinationBase" value="ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com"/>
        <setting name="roleAttribute" value="member"/>
        <setting name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true"/>
        <setting name="filter" value="(cn=*)"/>
        <setting name="readPermissionValue" value="read"/>
        <setting name="writePermissionValue" value="write"/>
      </security-setting-plugin>
    </security-settings>
  <!-- ... SNIP ... -->
</configuration>
```

A slightly modified version of my LDAP records:

```
version: 1

dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organization
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: top
dc: example
o: Example Inc.

dn: ou=User,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: User

dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
cn: admin
userPassword: {SSHA}3++NsuMU6iOErazxJNROGPmk1iw9Nboa
description: LDAP administrator

dn: ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Group

dn: ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Services

dn: ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Destination

dn: uid=CT84Ac0k,ou=User,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: uidObject
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: CT84Ac0k
uid: CT84Ac0k
userPassword: {SSHA}ZGpJdZ3CRyP35pltd16Fbydnhfw6HmzV

dn: cn=users,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: users
member: uid=CT84Ac0k

dn: cn=admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: admins
member: uid=admin

dn: cn=mqbroker,ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: mqbroker
userPassword: {SSHA}lcLtOtmqIT4BjB7hlhV60H2dzUH0C5bb

dn: ou=Queue,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Queue

dn: ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Topic

dn: cn=ActiveMQ.Advisory.$,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: applicationProcess
objectClass: top
cn: ActiveMQ.Advisory.$
description: A destination represents the target for which an ArtemisRole ca
 n get access

dn: cn=public.foo.test1.#,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: applicationProcess
objectClass: top
cn: public.foo.test1.#

dn: cn=read,cn=ActiveMQ.Advisory.$,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: read
member: cn=admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
member: cn=users,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=admin,cn=ActiveMQ.Advisory.$,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: admin
member: cn=admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=write,cn=ActiveMQ.Advisory.$,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: write
member: cn=admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
member: cn=users,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=read,cn=public.foo.test1.#,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: read
member: cn=admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
member: cn=users,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=admin,cn=public.foo.test1.#,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: admin
member: cn=admins,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=write,cn=public.foo.test1.#,ou=Topic,ou=Destination,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: write
member: cn=users,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks for your input. I've added the `bin/artemis producer` logs and also tried to remove the unavailable directives from the `login.config` - the issue seems still to persist though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your `login.config`. The `readTimeout` and `connectionTimeout` values need to be in quotes, e.g.:

```
openldap {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule required
        debug=true
        initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
        connectionURL="ldap://ldapserver:389"
        connectionUsername="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
        connectionPassword="..."
        connectionProtocol="s"
        connectionTimeout="10000"
        readTimeout="10000"
        authentication=simple
        ignorePartialResultException=true
        userBase="ou=User,dc=example,dc=com"
        userSearchMatching="(uid={0})"
        userSearchSubtree=false
        roleBase="ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com"
        roleName="cn"
        roleSearchMatching="(member:=uid={1})"
        roleSearchSubtree=true
    ;
};
```

**Note:** I removed `topicSearchMatchingFormat`, `topicSearchSubtreeBool`, `queueSearchMatchingFormat`, & `queueSearchSubtreeBool` because `org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule` doesn't support them. Having them in there doesn't technically cause a problem, but it makes it easier to read & understand with them gone.

Comment: Wow, that's tough. I did not suspect those two directives to fail due to missing quotes. Anyway, this helped to get around the issue in question, thanks a lot!